# League\Csv Read Without Filtering Empty Rows/Lines

Tags: php, csv, thephpleague

I'm using [League\Csv](https://csv.thephpleague.com/) to reformat CSVs. I'm reading in a CSV, manipulating the data, then writing the result out to a new CSV.

[Reading the docs](https://csv.thephpleague.com/9.0/reader/#readergetrecords-basic-usage) it says when reading a CSV it will

> Filter out the empty lines;

Is there any way to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a Statement object to process the Reader? It gives you more control over the selected rows. Perhaps the default statement would not include empty row filtering.

https://csv.thephpleague.com/9.0/reader/

See Records Selection, Advanced Usage.

Comment: I did try that but it seemed to yield the same result for me and there didn't seem to be any API to remove filters